# jquery chosen plugin doesn't give the chosen value

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

How to get the value that is currently selected for a select that has the chosen plugin applied to it. The way that I initialized it is:

```
$(container).find('.addKeywordTerm [name="addMatchType"]').chosen();
$(container).find('.addKeywordTerm .chzn-search').hide();
```

And what I do to try to retrieve the value is:

```
$(container).find('.addKeywordTerm [name="addMatchType"]').val()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the selector, you may change the "[name="addMatchType"]" to id or to "select[name="addMatchType"]" or try alerting its name to see if it is selecting correctly! :)